# Ошибка после скачивания WebView в javafx

Tags: java, html, javafx, intellij-idea, webview

Работаю в intellij idea, и для того, чтобы сделать "браузер" на javafx пришлось скачать WebView, прошёл 5 кругов ада и всё установил (через maven) после чего все импорты подтянулись. НО, при создании сцены выходит ошибка, как её можно решить? Или для просмотра html (локального) можно сделать по-другому???

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web@18.0.1/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:722)
    at javafx.web@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:579)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.sun.prism.ResourceFactory.isDisposed()'
    at javafx.web@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.webkit.prism.WCPageBackBufferImpl.validate(WCPageBackBufferImpl.java:99)
    at javafx.web@18.0.1/com.sun.webkit.WebPage.paint(WebPage.java:722)
    at javafx.web@18.0.1/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView.renderContent(NGWebView.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:270)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:579)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2072)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1964)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:479)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:328)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: #2f2f2f;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <WebView layoutX="7.0" layoutY="5.0" prefHeight="391.0" prefWidth="590.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: У вас где то вызывается метод isDispose и он не может его найти.
Прикрепите код в котором возникает ошибка

Comment: я просто в fxml добавил WebViev с id и в классе всё сделал что бы это просто запускалось, но нет, не работает

Comment: руками добавлял? или через SceneBuilder?

Comment: через SceneBuilder

Comment: в интернете пытался найти текст, что бы сделать без fxml, но не работает. Ошибка вроде как та же

Comment: а для просмотра html (локального) можно сделать по-другому?

Comment: А ты обработал его в контроллере?

Comment: да, я и обработал в контроллере, и сделал так, что бы не надо было обрабатывать, но оно не работает.
Ну как не работает, запускается экран белый и всё.
И печатается ошибка.

Comment: не, я может и не знаю как его обработать, сможете скинуть проект с webView где просто открывается google

Comment: ХМММ, я загрузил новее версию (до этого была версия 17 18), но видимо версия 15 новее (я сам не понял) и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставил другую версию: org.jfxcore:javafx-web:15-ea+1